# How to re.split() a string with complex capturing group?

Tags: python, split, python-re

I want split a string(e.g. `'foo <t>XXX</t> bar'`) by group of strings surrounded by tags and tags.

The following method works fine though。

```
>>> re.split(r'(<t>.+?</t>)', 'foo <t>XXX</t> bar')
['foo ', '<t>XXX</t>', ' bar']
```

Because the tag name is not limited to x, I tried to group references but not getting the expected results.

```
>>> re.split(r'(<(.+?)>.+?</\2>)', 'foo <t>XXX</t> bar')
['foo ', '<t>XXX</t>', 't', ' bar']
```

What should I do?

Comment: What's your end goal here?

Comment: My goal is split 'foo <t>XXX</t> bar' to ['foo ', '<t>XXX</t>', ' bar']

Answer (score 0):

You [infamously can't use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/51685) regexps to parse HTML, but you can use `re.split` to *tokenize* a tag-structured string, and parse it into a tree of expressions:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint


def parse_tag_string(tag_string):
    # Stack of tag-name/children structures.
    stack = [(None, [])]

    for i, bit in enumerate(re.split(r"(<[^>]+>)", tag_string)):
        # When using capturing groups, the splitter is included in the result;
        # every 2nd item (if there's 1 capturing group) is the splitter.
        if i % 2 == 0:
            # Bare string, just push onto our current node (unless it's empty).
            if bit:
                stack[-1][1].append(bit)
        else:
            name = bit.strip("<>")
            if name.startswith("/"):  # Handle closing tags
                name = name[1:]
                if stack[-1][0] != name:
                    raise ValueError(
                        f"Mismatched closing tag: {bit!r}; " f"expected {stack[-1][0]!r}"
                    )
                stack.pop()
            else:  # Handle opening tags
                # Create new child with no children of its own
                child = (name, [])
                # Put it in our current node
                stack[-1][1].append(child)
                # And make it our current node
                stack.append(child)
    if len(stack) != 1:
        raise ValueError(f"Unclosed tags: {stack[1:]}")
    return stack.pop()[1]


parsed = parse_tag_string('foo <t>XXX<b>bar</b></t> bar')
pprint(parsed, width=40)
```

This prints out

```
['foo ',
 ('t', ['XXX', ('b', ['bar'])]),
 ' bar']
```

– a list that contains other either strings or 2-tuples whose first member is the tag name and the second member a list like this.

You can then e.g. pretty-print this:

```
def pretty_print_parsed(parsed, level=0):
    indent = "  " * level
    for item in parsed:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            print(f"{indent}{item}")
        else:
            print(f"{indent}<{item[0]}>")
            pretty_print_parsed(item[1], level + 1)
            print(f"{indent}</{item[0]}>")
```

yields

```
foo 
<t>
  XXX
  <b>
    bar
  </b>
</t>
 bar
```

or just rip out all of the tags by walking the tree and only outputting the text:

```
def detag(parsed):
    return ''.join(
        item if isinstance(item, str) else detag(item[1])
        for item in parsed
    )
print(detag(parsed)) # 'foo XXXbar bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to avoid the nested grouping by

```py
import re

string = "foo <t>XXX</t> bar"
splitted = re.split("(" + "|".join(rf"<{x}>.+?</{x}>" for x in "tyz") + ")", string)
```

to get

```py
['foo ', '<t>XXX</t>', ' bar']
```